# How to use font awesome icon or google icon (material icon) in grid view of android xamarin.

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, font-awesome, google-material-icons

I am new in Android and Xamarin . i have grid view with image and text view in my xamarin (android) application . but i wont to use font awesome icon or material icon in place of image in grid view reason behind that is reduce size of application.i try this NuGet package but it's not work for me ["https://www.nuget.org/packages/FontAwesome.Xamarin/"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FontAwesome.Xamarin/)
but i don't found proper tutorial for that. so please help me for that and i have one another doubt when i use icon in place of .png so it's help me for reducing size of application or not??

Comment: You need to use appcompat v7, James Montemagno has a whole blog on the subject https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/